# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeClass' of undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined, typeerror, removeclass

i've got a problem with my jquery code i feel the solution is quite simple but i just can't get it, it's a simple .on click function on an element with a class But when i click on the element  it gives me this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeClass' of undefined" does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?

```
$("body").on( "click", ".fa-caret-right", function(e) {
    e.trigger.removeClass("fa-caret-right");             // <--- right here
    e.trigger.addClass("fa-caret-down");
    e.trigger.parent().next().css("display", "block");
});
$("body").on( "click", ".fa-caret-down", function(e) {
    e.trigger.removeClass("fa-caret-down");             // <--- and probably here
    e.trigger.addClass("fa-caret-right");
    e.trigger.parent().next().css("display", "none");
});
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e` is [the `Event` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), which doesn't have a property called `trigger`.  Since `trigger` doesn't exist, you can't call functions on it.

What are you *trying* to do here?:

```
e.trigger.removeClass("fa-caret-right");
```

If you want to remove the class from the element which invoked the handler (the element which was clicked), you can reference that element with `this`:

```
$(this).removeClass("fa-caret-right");
```

Or, if you want to use the `Event` object, you may be looking for [the `target` property](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
e.target.removeClass("fa-caret-right");
```

Comment: i wanted to use the event object and mixed up trigger and target =p thank you!